# How to call the tick() method

Tags: java, time, minecraft

I am trying to program a minecraft clone.
In the current state i have a little world and i can also walk around but now i am stuck with the tick method. I'm calling this tick method in the main method in the while loop.

While loop in the main method:

```
boolean closeRequested = false;
while(!closeRequested){

    mc.tick();

    if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_ESCAPE)){
        closeRequested = true;
    }

    if(Display.isCloseRequested()){
        closeRequested = true;
    }
```

Tick Method:

```
public void tick()
  {
    while (Keyboard.next()) {
      if (Keyboard.getEventKeyState())
      {
        if (Keyboard.getEventKey() == 28) {
          Minecraft.level.save();
        }
        if (Keyboard.getEventKey() == 2) {
          this.paintTexture = 1;
        }
        if (Keyboard.getEventKey() == 3) {
          this.paintTexture = 3;
        }
        if (Keyboard.getEventKey() == 4) {
          this.paintTexture = 4;
        }
        if (Keyboard.getEventKey() == 5) {
          this.paintTexture = 5;
        }
        if (Keyboard.getEventKey() == 7) {
          this.paintTexture = 6;
        }
      }
    }
    Minecraft.level.tick();
    Minecraft.particleEngine.tick();
    Minecraft.player.tick();   //This is the movement
  }
```

Player Tick Method:

```
public void tick()
{
this.xo = this.x;
this.yo = this.y;
this.zo = this.z;
float xa = 0.0F;
float ya = 0.0F;
if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(19)) {
  resetPos();
}
if ((Keyboard.isKeyDown(200)) || (Keyboard.isKeyDown(17))) {
  ya -= 1.0F;
}
if ((Keyboard.isKeyDown(208)) || (Keyboard.isKeyDown(31))) {
  ya += 1.0F;
}
if ((Keyboard.isKeyDown(203)) || (Keyboard.isKeyDown(30))) {
  xa -= 1.0F;
}
if ((Keyboard.isKeyDown(205)) || (Keyboard.isKeyDown(32))) {
  xa += 1.0F;
}
if ((Keyboard.isKeyDown(57)) || (Keyboard.isKeyDown(219))) {
  if (this.onGround) {
    this.yd = 0.5F;
  }
}
moveRelative(xa, ya, this.onGround ? 0.1F : 0.02F);

this.yd = ((float)(this.yd - 0.08D));
move(this.xd, this.yd, this.zd);
this.xd *= 0.91F;
this.yd *= 0.98F;
this.zd *= 0.91F;
if (this.onGround)
{
  this.xd *= 0.7F;
  this.zd *= 0.7F;
}
```

}

When i call this method like this the player moves like sonic and also its depending on the fps how fast the player moves.

I've got some of this code from a minecraft alpha version but i couldn't find the point where the `tick()` method is called.

I want the player to move in a constant speed.

I also have a timer where i can get some variables like timepassed, fps or also the ticks (the timer is also from the original minecraft code).

Comment: Well, you are running this without pause. So the `tick` calls will be done as fast as CPU/OS permit it. EDIT : If you are not doing any sleep/pause of the thread in any methods, you don't need to add more code ;)

Comment: Also, you should really think about structuring your code a bit better, if your `while-loop` is just in your `main` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your code:

```
while(!closeRequested){
    mc.tick();
    //do stuff here that runs every 20 times in a second
    Thread.sleep(50); //Sleep for 50 milliseconds, which is default minecraft gametick
}
```

Without the sleep() the loop will run as fast as it can, causing the problem of yours. A simple way sleep() will make it rest for a moment before countiuing the loop again.

Comment: One more thing: If you're keen on building a game, a hard coded 50 ms sleep is really bad style! You'd need to implement some sort of Game loop. Definitely check out http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=24220.0 which will get you started on concepts of time and frame management in game development!